# how to load external stylesheet of smarty template in dompdf

Tags: php, pdf-generation, smarty, dompdf

i am trying to generate a pdf file from smarty template using dompdf:
code is below:-

```
require_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($smarty->fetch(CURRENT_TEMPLATE.'/module/shopping_cart.html'));
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

i am getting the pdf file.but i am getting pdf file without any styles,i found that dompdf is not loading external stylesheet.so how can i load external stylesheet in smarty template

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$dompdf->load->html()`. Because of this styles are loaded *relative to the PHP document in the local file system*, not relative to the web server root. The easiest fix is to include the full URL (e.g. http://example.com/style.css) when referencing external styles.